# how can i generate ssis packages from biml using commandline and deploy ssis on server

Tags: ssis, automation, biml

I worked on creating biml. generate ssis packages from that. build SSIS project and then deploy ispac file on server.

but can these all manual steps be automated?
can i generate ssis from biml using commandline? what are the commands and what are the prerequisites to be installed on machine for this other than bidshelper

after that can i build my integration services project having ssis generated from biml and deploy it on server using commandline? again what are the pre-req. required to be installed for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below command after installing Mist 4.0 worked to generate ispac file from biml

```
bimlc.exe -s "C:\\temp\\Project.biml" -s "C:\\temp\\DwToDw.biml" -t "C:\\temp\\ispacfile\\" -v=2014 --ssisDeploymentModel=Project
```

Answer (score 2):

Automating the emission of SSIS packages from Biml is going to require access to the core bimlengine. Access to the biml engine comes via a licensed installation of [Mist/soon-to-be-rebranded-BimlStudio](https://varigence.com/Mist)

Conversion of a dtproj to ispac is going to require you to create and install an [MSBuild extension](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) which I cover in my talk, [DevOps for SSIS](http://www.sqlsaturday.com/441/Sessions/Details.aspx?sid=38643)
The msbuild parameters and the process is outlined under [Building SSIS 2012 using MSBuild – A Journey to DB deployment automation](https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/)

Comment: Thanks billinkc. i'll look at your blog as well as Mist.i tried with Mist trial version using bimlc.exe but it is generating a new project while i want to add ssis packages to my existing project. generate only dtsx the way we do using right click on biml and select generate SSIS. do you have any idea about is it possible by adding any options to the command?

Comment: Hi @billinkc i tried with Mist tria version to generate ssis package from biml file. using bimlc.exe. but after opening the project its gives error for all DFT as below
The contact information for this task is "Performs high-performance data extraction, transformation and loading;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server v10; (C) 2007 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1
any idea what m i missing?