# Dynamically merge the two tables using primary key

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a procedure where I can dynamically merge a number of staging+destination tables, each with different column names and primary keys.

Is there a way to merge by extracting the primary key constraint?

I envisioned doing a dynamic SQL statement which looked like this:

```
'MERGE
   ' + @DestinationTable + ' Dest
USING
   ' + @StagingTable ' Staging
ON
   ' + @JoinConditions + '
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT INTO
      Dest
   SELECT
      *
   FROM
      Staging
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      Dest
   SET
      ' + @UpdateStatement
```

Where `@DestinationTable` is a string parameter with the table name, `@StagingTable` is the same, `@JoinConditions` is a string which is of the format

```
Staging.ColumnName = Dest.ColumnName
```

for each key column, and `@UpdateStatement` is of the same format except with non-key columns.

It doesn't look pretty, but this is how I foresee it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating MERGE statements is a staple of the BI/DW space because it is a common requirement.

There are solutions that generate a stored proc and/or merge statements, [some will also write the SSIS packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600033/how-can-i-generate-ssis-packages-from-biml-using-commandline-and-deploy-ssis-on). There

On that note, I'm not going to write a solution here.
I downloaded one last time I needed it

You can get a feel for how common this requirement is by searching "generate merge script sql server"

For example

- https://github.com/readyroll/generate-sql-merge
- https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/generate-a-merge-statement-from-table-structure/
- http://billg.sqlteam.com/2011/02/15/generate-merge-statements-from-a-table/

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually a new BI developer, so this is all learning for me. Appreciate the push in the right direction.